# How to reset settings in c# httpClient?

Tags: c#, http

In c#, I make get and post requests. This is my code

GET

```
private async Task<string> GetAsync(string uri, Token token, string accept, string content_type)
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(accept)); // ACCEPT header
        bool added = client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "text/xml");
        if (token != null) client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(token.token_type, token.access_token);

        HttpResponseMessage g = await client.GetAsync(uri);
        if (g.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return await g.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            errors.AddError(g.ReasonPhrase, await g.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            return null;
        }
}
```

POST

```
private async Task<string> PostAsync(string uri, Token token, string postData, string accept, string content_type)
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(accept)); // ACCEPT header
        if (token != null) client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(token.token_type, token.access_token);

        var content = new StringContent(postData, Encoding.UTF8, content_type);

        HttpResponseMessage g = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
        if (g.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return await g.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            errors.AddError(g.ReasonPhrase, await g.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            return null;
        }
}
```

But I read that you should reuse the httpclient like this

```
private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

as I make lots of frequent requests. However if I re-use the object, the settings like headers persist and that causes issues. Is there a way I can just reset the settings but keep the object?

Thanks

Comment: You can add the headers to the request object, instead of having them in the _client's_ default request headers.

Comment: I think it's OK to instantiate a new instance if you need a blank slate. You just don't want to create a new one with every single request for no reason.

Comment: I don't think it will let you edit the attributes of the client once you've made a request with it.

Comment: How can I do the request object? That seems like it might work.

Comment: Unrelated, but why are you mixing `async`/`await` with synchronous code like `client.GetAsync(uri).Result`?

Comment: @omega you are already doing half the work, `HttpRequestMessage` has a "Headers" property.  See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage.headers(v=vs.118).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.httprequestheaders(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: I would prefer it to be async, but how would I write the code for that?

Comment: If you're using asp.net core, you might take a look at using [HttpClientFactory](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HttpClientFactoryForTypedHttpClientInstancesInASPNETCore21.aspx).

Comment: The same way you make any other code async compatible. Change the method to return a Task and mark it as async. Await all asynchronous calls within it. All the way up the callstack. Make sure you read over [Best Practices in Async/Await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) so you don't make any common errors like accessing .Result

Comment: I second what @Chris has said.  Even if you get the shared `HttpClient` working with our recommendations you still have to worry about the singleton `HttpClient` not respecting DNS changes.  The `HttpClientFactory` solves both issues

Comment: @maccettura the link uses HttpWebRequest , which is now considered old. The new standard is HttpClient.

Comment: And i'm using asp.net 4.5

Comment: I added the full function code, how do  I make it fully async?

Comment: @omega change `HttpResponseMessage g = client.GetAsync(uri).Result;` for `HttpResponseMessage g = await client.GetAsync(uri);`. Apply this same change in other `async` calls.

Comment: When I change it for the Post one, it breaks.

Comment: @omega I posted the wrong link originally but edited immediately after.  Check again

Comment: How would I do headers with HttpClient? (without setting defaults)

Comment: @omega you set the headers of the `HttpRequestMessage` object.  So you are setting on a per request basis and not on the client itself.  The [second link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage.headers(v=vs.118).aspx) in my previous comment is what you are looking for

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use the HttpClient's default headers.  Set the headers on the request:

```
var content = new StringContent(postData, Encoding.UTF8, content_type) // CONTENT-TYPE header
content.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(accept)); // ACCEPT header
if (token != null) 
    content.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(token.token_type, token.access_token);
```

Then all threads can use the same HttpClient throughout the runtime of the application without issue.

Comment: How would I do this, but still keep it async. I updated my code above. Can you edit your code to work with that?

Comment: @omega Headers is on the content object now after your edit.